# Using a struct from a different library in Cython

Tags: python, c, struct, cython

I am trying to call a C function in Cython and the header looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <apriltag.h>
#include <tag36h11.h>

#include <common/getopt.h>
#include <common/image_u8.h>
#include <common/image_u8x4.h>
#include <common/pjpeg.h>
#include <common/zarray.h>

apriltag_detection_t* scan_frame(int width, int height, uint8_t* data);
```

As you can see, I want to return an array of structs, which are type defined to be `apriltag_detection_t`. According to the [documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html), in order to be able to use this in Cython, I must define some sort of `pxd` file which is essentially a copy of header.

However, `apriltag_detection_t` is a type that is already defined in `apriltag.h`. Furthermore, `apriltag_detection_t` has members that are already defined in `apriltag.h`. Do I have to recursively redefine all of these types (by hand) in the Cython file before being able to use this library? Where would I write them?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 6**

Finally at the step of wrapping a function!

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint8_t

cdef extern from "<apriltag.h>":
    cdef struct apriltag_detection:
        int id
        double c[2]
        double p[4][2]

    ctypedef apriltag_detection apriltag_detection_t

cdef extern from "tag36h11_detector/tag36h11_detector.h":
    apriltag_detection_t* scan_frame(int width, int height, uint8_t* data);

def detect(width, height, frame):
    return scan_frame(width, height, frame)
```

> tag36h11_detector.pyx:15:21: Cannot convert 'apriltag_detection_t *' to Python object

`apriltag_detection_t*` is meant to be an array of structs

**UPDATE 5**
This seems to have worked.

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint8_t

cdef extern from "<apriltag.h>":
    cdef struct apriltag_detection:
        int id
        double c[2]
        double p[4][2]

    ctypedef apriltag_detection apriltag_detection_t

cdef extern from "tag36h11_detector/tag36h11_detector.h":
    apriltag_detection_t* scan_frame(int width, int height, uint8_t* data);
```

**UPDATE 4**
Solved the previous issues by importing the necessary types.

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint8_t

cdef extern from "apriltag.h":
    cdef struct apriltag_detection:
        int id
        double c[2]
        double p[4][2]

    ctypedef apriltag_detection apriltag_detection_t

cdef extern from "tag36h11_detector.h":
    apriltag_detection_t* scan_frame(int width, int height, uint8_t* data);
```

> tag36h11_detector.c:533:10: fatal error: 'apriltag.h' file not found

I'm not sure where this is coming from because my header file, as provided in the original post, required `<apriltag.h>` and not `"apriltag.h"`. This is what my `setup.py` looks like.

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize(Extension(\
    name='tag36h11_detector', \
    sources=["tag36h11_detector.pyx", \
    "tag36h11_detector/tag36h11_detector.c"], \
    include_path=["/usr/local/include/apriltag"], \
    libraries=["apriltag"])))
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
cdef extern from "apriltag.h":
    cdef struct apriltag_detection:
        int id
        double c[2]
        double p[4][2]

    ctypedef apriltag_detection apriltag_detection_t

cdef extern from "tag36h11_detector.h":
    apriltag_detection_t* scan_frame(int width, int height, uint8_t* data);
```

> tag36h11_detector.pyx:10:60: 'uint8_t' is not a type identifier

**UPDATE 2**

This is my current code and the following is the compilation error

```
// tag36h11_detector.pyx
cdef extern from "apriltag.h":
    ctypedef apriltag_detection_t:
        int id
        double c[2]
        double p[4][2]

cdef extern from "tag36h11_detector.h":
    apriltag_detection_t* scan_frame(int width, int height, uint8_t* data);

// apriltag.h
    ...
    typedef struct apriltag_detector apriltag_detector_t;
    ...
```

> tag36h11_detector.pyx:2:33: Syntax error in ctypedef statement

**UPDATE 1**

So I'm trying to interface with the above header file with Python (which I wrote and implemented) with types defined in `apriltag.h` (from a library).

```
cdef extern from "apriltag.h":
    struct apriltag_detection:
        int id
        double c[2]
        double p[4][2]

cdef extern from "tag36h11_detector.h":
    struct apriltag_detection* scan_frame(int width, int height, uint8_t* data);
```

When I try compiling the above, I get

> tag36h11_detector.pyx:8:29: Syntax error in struct or union definition

Comment: For your updated question, have you tried defining the structs as `ctypedef struct apriltag_detection` instead in your pxd file?

Comment: @CodeSurgeon same error. Also, I wrote all of the above on a `.pyx` file, as the answer below said.

Comment: I think you don't need "struct" prior to 'apriltag_detection" in the last line. See also the way the function is imported in the example

Comment: Interesting. Usually, I actually write my c-library wrappers in a separate pxd file. When writing them, I found some online examples to be helpful. These ones are for [OpenGL](https://gist.github.com/krischer/4219796) and [SDL2](https://gist.github.com/krischer/4219808) respectively that gave me some assistance. And [here](https://gist.github.com/AnishN/860776e75f58dc8595f7955198af42a8) is an incomplete one that I am currently in the process of writing for the chipmunk physics library. Hope these examples help to give you a different approach!

Comment: @ead The `struct` in the original header, `apriltag.h` is actually `typedef struct apriltag_detection apriltag_detection_t`, so I tried accounting for that but I'm getting a different error

Comment: You are fast! If path to header is relative to the pyx-file (e.g. In the same folder) then " " should be used, if from include-path, then "<>"

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I think I'm close.. I'm having the error "Cannot convert `apriltag_detection_t*` to Python object". This is an array of structs, so I'm not sure how to write the appropriate Cython code

Comment: There are no pointers in python. If you want to use this function and its result in python, you have to covert data to a python object(dictionary or a handmade class) or declare this function 'cdef' otherwise

Comment: @ead thanks. I have opened a new question here with some updated code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515782/returning-an-array-of-structs-in-cython?noredirect=1#comment79985875_46515782 If I declare the function as `cdef`, how will I interpret the return type in my Python code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is basically covered in [this part of cython documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html), which says that you only need to import parts, which you will be using in your cython code.

For example let's take a look at the following C interface:

```
#struct.h
struct Needed{
  int a;
};

struct NotNeeded{
  int b;
};

struct Combined{
  struct Needed needed;
  struct NotNeeded notneeded;
};

struct Combined create(void);
```

You would like to call the function `create` and use the value `a` from the `Needed` struct, that means you have to import `struct Needed` and parts of `struct Combined` but not `NotNeeded` in your cython code:

```
#struct_import.pyx
cdef extern from "struct.h":
     struct Needed:   # use "ctypedef struct Needed" if defined with typedef in h-file! 
            int a  
     struct Combined:  #NotNeeded is missing!
          Needed needed 
     Combined create()  

def get_needed():
    return create().needed.a #should be 42!
```

Now, using `setup.py` (its content can be seen further below, the same goes for the content of `struct.c`to) we get the expected result:

```
[] python setup.py build_ext --inplace
[] python -c "python -c "import struct_import as si; print si.get_needed()"
    42
```

---

If you use cython to glue some C code together, it is possible, even less is necessary. In oour example, if we had a C-function which would extract the needed value from the `Combined` struct:

```
#struct.h 
...
int extract(struct Combined combined);//returns combined.needed.a
```

We could use it as follows in the pyx-file:

```
#struct_import.pyx
cdef extern from "struct.h":
     struct Combined: 
          pass  #nothing imported!
     Combined create()  
     int extract(Combined combined)

def get_needed():
    return extract(create()) #should be 42!
```

And despite we didn't import the `Needed` struct at all, it works as good as the first version.

So if it becomes a chore to import all those structs, one could extend the c interface to make it unnecessary.

---

To make the example complete, here the missing setup.py and struct.c files:

```
#setup.py:
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize(Extension(
            name='struct_import',
            sources = ["struct_import.pyx", "struct.c"]
    )))
```

and

```
//struct.c
#include "struct.h"

struct Combined create(){
  struct Combined res;
  res.needed.a=42;
  res.notneeded.b=21;
  return res;
}

int extract(struct Combined combined){
   return combined.needed.a;
}
```