# Returning an array of structs in Cython

Tags: python, c, arrays, struct, cython

I'm trying to return an array of structs in Cython.

```
// .pyx

from libc.stdint cimport uint8_t

cdef extern from "<apriltag.h>":
    cdef struct apriltag_detection:
        int id
        double c[2]
        double p[4][2]

    ctypedef apriltag_detection apriltag_detection_t

cdef extern from "tag36h11_detector/tag36h11_detector.h":
    apriltag_detection_t* scan_frame(int width, int height, uint8_t* data);

cdef class Detection:
    # how do I "link" this to the struct defined above?
    def __cinit__(self):
        pass
    def __dealloc__(self):
        pass

def detect(width, height, frame):
    return scan_frame(width, height, frame)
```

Ideally, I would like to call the `detect` function in Python code, and get a list of `Detection` objects where `Detection` is a wrapper class for the C struct `apriltag_detection` which is typedef'd to `apriltag_detection_t`.

I'm getting the following compilation error:

> tag36h11_detector.pyx:22:21: Cannot convert 'apriltag_detection_t *' to Python object

I can't find a reference to returning a pointer to a struct, or an array of structs, anywhere in the documentation.

**UPDATE 3**

```
// .h
typedef struct detection_payload {
    int size;
    apriltag_detection_t** detections;
} detection_payload_t;
```

I'm trying to convert the above struct into a Python object that holds `size` and a Python list that holds `apriltag_detection_t` objects.

```
// .pyx

cdef extern from "<apriltag.h>":
    cdef struct apriltag_detection:
        int id
        double c[2]
        double p[4][2]

    ctypedef apriltag_detection apriltag_detection_t

cdef extern from "tag36h11_detector/tag36h11_detector.h":
    cdef struct detection_payload:
        int size
        apriltag_detection_t** detections
    ctypedef detection_payload detection_payload_t
    detection_payload* scan_frame(int width, int height, uint8_t* data)

...


cdef class Detection:
    cdef apriltag_detection* _d

    def __cinit__(self):
        self._d = NULL
    cdef _setup(self, apriltag_detection* d):
        self._d = d
    def __dealloc__(self):
        self._d = NULL
    property id:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._d.id
    property c:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._d.c
    property p:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._d.p

cdef Detection_create(apriltag_detection_t* d):
    return Detection()._setup(d)

cdef class DetectionPayload:
    cdef detection_payload* _p

    def __cinit__(self):
        self._p = NULL
    cdef _setup(self, detection_payload* p):
        self._p = p
        self.size = p.size
        self.detections = []
        for i in range(0, self.size):
            apriltag_detection_t* detection = self._p.detections[i]
            d = Detection_create(detection)
            self.detections+=[d]
    def __dealloc__(self):
        _p = NULL
    property size:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.size
    property detections:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.detections
```

I'm getting several syntax errors on the line:

```
apriltag_detection_t* detection = self._p.detections[I]
```

Specifically, on the pointer `apriltag_detection_t*`

**UPDATE 2**

This compiles and imports fine now. Still no progress on arrays

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint8_t

cdef extern from "<apriltag.h>":
    cdef struct apriltag_detection:
        int id
        double c[2]
        double p[4][2]

    ctypedef apriltag_detection apriltag_detection_t

cdef extern from "tag36h11_detector/tag36h11_detector.h":
    apriltag_detection_t* scan_frame(int width, int height, uint8_t* data);

cdef class Detection:
    cdef apriltag_detection* _d

    def __cinit__(self):
        self._d = NULL
    cdef _setup(self, apriltag_detection* d):
        self._d = d
    def __dealloc__(self):
        self._d = NULL
    property id:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._d.id
    property c:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._d.c
    property p:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._d.p

cdef Detection_create(apriltag_detection_t* d):
    return Detection()._setup(d)

def detect(width, height, frame):
    cdef apriltag_detection_t* detection = scan_frame(width, height, frame)
    return Detection_create(detection)
```

**UPDATE 1**

I tried following the post linked below, and this is what I have so far.

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint8_t

cdef extern from "<apriltag.h>":
    cdef struct apriltag_detection:
        int id
        double c[2]
        double p[4][2]

    ctypedef apriltag_detection apriltag_detection_t

cdef extern from "tag36h11_detector/tag36h11_detector.h":
    apriltag_detection_t* scan_frame(int width, int height, uint8_t* data);

cdef class Detection:
    cdef apriltag_detection* _d;
    def __cinit__(self):
        self._d = NULL
    def _setup(self, apriltag_detection* d):
        self._d = d
    def __dealloc__(self):
        self._d = NULL
    property id:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._t.id
    property c:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._t.c
    property p:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._t.p

cdef Detection_create(apriltag_detection_t* d):
    return Detection()._setup(d)

def detect(width, height, frame):
    return <Detection>scan_frame(width, height, frame)
```

Although this is closer than I was before, I'm still getting the error:

> tag36h11_detector.pyx:33:30: Cannot convert 'apriltag_detection_t *' to Python object

On the line

```
cdef Detection_create(apriltag_detection_t* d):
    return Detection()._setup(d)
```

Moreover, I have no idea how to return a Python list...

Comment: This is is very close to a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545875/wrapping-casting-c-struct-in-cython-to-python-class. It's about a single struct rather than an array but the idea is very close to the same

Comment: @DavidW thank you but but using their code has resulted in the same error. I also don't know how to return a Python list...

Comment: Not a solution for your current problem, but the next ;) because 'frame' is not a pointer http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/array.html

Comment: Btw, if scan_frame returns an array, how do you know how many tags are in array?

Comment: @ead Ah..I don't! Perhaps I should return a struct that contains the size and points to an array of `apriltag_detection_t`s?

Comment: That would be a clean way to solve this issue!

Comment: @ead thanks! I've tried doing that and I think I'm close. I've updated the OP with the latest issue I'm having

Comment: It looks like you're very close to the right answer. I don't think you need a `**` pointer in the struct - I think it could just be a single `*`. Then do `apriltag_detection_t* detection = &self._p.detections[i]` (i.e. get array element then get the address)

Comment: @DavidW I did that, here are all the errors I'm getting https://pastebin.com/za8QLFtb

Comment: `cdef apriltag_detection_t* detection` (needs to be outside the loop to define the variable, then you can assign to it with `detection = &self._p.detections[i]` inside the loop)

Comment: @DavidW that did the trick, thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant here, but it is possible to map a `c` `struct` onto a structured array `dtype`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035287/passing-structured-array-to-cython-failed-i-think-it-is-a-cython-bug

Comment: See [identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686590/initializing-cython-objects-with-existing-c-objects/45038660#45038660) on how to map C pointers to Python objects in Cython. In short, define a cdef class with a C pointer member and assign the pointer in a factory function that returns a new python object - an instance of the cdef class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have solved your problems, but I would like to answer the question nevertheless. First because I would like to try it out and second because I think you have some problems with memory management and I would like to point it out.

We will wrap the following simple C-interface:

```
//creator.h
typedef struct {
   int mult;
   int add;
} Result;

typedef struct {
   int size;
   Result *arr;
} ResultArray;

ResultArray create(int size, int *input){
   //whole file at the end of the answer
}
```

which  processes the input-array and return a C-array of structs along with the number of elements in this array.

Our wrapping pyx-file looks then like following:

```
#result_import.pyx (verion 0)
cdef extern from "creator.h":
     ctypedef struct Result:
          int mult
          int add
     ctypedef struct ResultArray:
          int size
          Result *arr
     ResultArray create(int size, int *input)

def create_structs(int[::1] input_vals):
    pass
```

The most notable part: I use a memoryview (`int[::1]`) to pass my input array and this has two advantages:

1. On the python-side it is possible to use anything that supports memory views (`numpy`, `array` since Python3) which is more flexible as to use a numpy array
2. It is ensured (through `[::1]`) that the input is continuous

In the test-script I use numpy, but one could also go with build-in array:

```
#test.py
import result_import
import numpy as np

a=np.array([1,2,3],dtype='int32')
result=result_import.create_structs(a)
for i,el in enumerate(result):
    print  i, ": mult:", el.mult, " add:", el.add
```

Now nothing works yet, but everything is set up.

**First scenario:** we just wanna have normal python-objects nothing fancy! One possibility would be:

```
#result_import.pyx (verion 1)
#from cpython cimport array needed for array.array in Python2
from libc.stdlib cimport free
....
class PyResult:
    def __init__(self, mult, add):
       self.mult=mult
       self.add=add


def create_structs(int[::1] input_vals):
    cdef ResultArray res=create(len(input_vals), &input_vals[0])
    try:
        lst=[]
        for i in range(res.size):
            lst.append(PyResult(res.arr[i].mult, res.arr[i].add))
    finally:
        free(res.arr)
    return lst
```

I convert the whole data to python-objects and use a simple list. Very simple, but there are two things worth noting:

1. Memory management: I'm responsible for freeing the memory allocated in res.arr. So I use `try...finally` to make sure it happens even if an exception is thrown.
2. It is not enough to set this pointer to `NULL`, I have to call `free`-function.

Now our `test.py` works - nice!

**Second scenario:** however if I need only some of the elements and convert them all - it is just inefficient. Furthermore, I keep all elements twice in the memory (at least for some time) - this is a downside of the naive approach. So I would like to create `PyResult`-objects on demand somewhere later in program.

Let's write a wrapper list:

```
#result_import.pyx (verion 2)
...
cdef class WrappingList:
    cdef int size
    cdef Result *arr

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.size=0
        self.arr=NULL

    def __dealloc__(self):
        free(self.arr)
        print "deallocated"#just a check

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index<0 or index>=self.size:
            raise IndexError("list index out of range")
        return PyResult(self.arr[index].mult, self.arr[index].add)


def create_structs(int[::1] input_vals):
    cdef ResultArray res=create(len(input_vals), &input_vals[0])
    lst=WrappingList()
    lst.size, lst.arr=res.size, res.arr
    return lst
```

So the class `WrappingList` behaves a lot like a list, keeps the whole C-array without copying and creates `PyResult`-objects only when needed. Things worth mentioning:

1. `__dealloc__` is called when the `WrapperingList`-object is destroyed - this is the place where we release the memory which was given to us by the C-code. At the end of `test.py` we should see "deallocated", otherwise something gone wrong...
2. `__getitem__` is used for iteration.

**Third scenario:** Python code should not only read the results but also change them, so the changed data can be passed back to the C-code. For that let's make `PyResult` a proxy:

```
#result_import.pyx (verion 3, last)
...
cdef class PyResult:
    cdef Result *ptr #ptr to my element
    def __init__(self):
       self.ptr=NULL

    @property
    def mult(self):
        return self.ptr.mult

    @mult.setter
    def mult(self, value):
        self.ptr.mult = value

    @property
    def add(self):
        return self.ptr.add

    @add.setter
    def add(self, value):
        self.ptr.add = value


cdef class WrappingList:  
    ...
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index>=self.size:
            raise IndexError("list index out of range")
        res=PyResult()
        res.ptr=&self.arr[index]
        return res
```

Now, the `PyResult`-object holds a pointer to the corresponding element and can change it directly in the C-array. However, there are some pitfalls, I should mention:

1. It's a little bit unsafe: `PyResult` should not live longer than the parent-`WrappingList`-object. You can fix it by adding a reference to parent in the `PyResult`-class.
2. Accessing the elements (`add` or `mult`) is quite costly, because every time a new Python-object must be created, registered and then deleted.

Let's change the test-script, to see the proxies in action:

```
#test.py(second version)
import result_import
import numpy as np

a=np.array([1,2,3],dtype='int32')
result=result_import.create_structs(a)
for i,el in enumerate(result):
    print  i, ": mult:", el.mult, " add:", el.add
    el.mult, el.add=42*i,21*i

# now print changed values:
for i,el in enumerate(result):
    print  i, ": mult:", el.mult, " add:", el.add
```

There is still a lot to improve, but I guess enough for one answer:)

---

Attachments:

Sloppy `creator.h` - one needs to check the result of `malloc`:

```
//creator.h
typedef struct {
   int mult;
   int add;
} Result;

typedef struct {
   int size;
   Result *arr;
} ResultArray;

ResultArray create(int size, int *input){
   ResultArray res;
   res.size=size;
   res.arr=(Result *)malloc(size*sizeof(Result));//todo: check !=0
   for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
       res.arr[i].mult=2*input[i];
       res.arr[i].add=2+input[i]; 
   }
   return res;
}
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize(Extension(
            name='result_import',
            sources = ["result_import.pyx"]
    )))
```